# Prove $\mathbb{P}( k < l/2 ) \geq \frac{l}{2} \times \mathbb{P}( k = l/4 ) $ for binomial variable $k$

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a Binomial variable: 
$$
k \sim Bin(l,\alpha)
$$
Is it possible to prove/disprove that: 
$$
\mathbb{P}( k < l/2 ) \geq \frac{l}{2} \times \mathbb{P}( k = l/4 )  
$$

EDIT: it's been used in 2nd line of 3rd paragraph in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.3564v4.pdf 
(page 33)

Comment: This isn't a proof by any means, but just looking at the [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#mediaviewer/File:Binomial_distribution_pmf.svg) for the binomial pmf, this appears to be true: the LHS is approximated by area under the pmf to the left of the mean.  The RHS approximates the area using $\mathbb{P}(k = l/4)$ as the average height.  Visually, it's clear that this is far less than the average height.  I'm not sure if this approach will lead anywhere, but it at least provides a bit of intuition, at least for me.

Comment: If $l$ is not a multiple of four, the RHS of the last inequality is simply zero, so the inequality holds vacuously. But I bet the interesting question comes from assuming $l=4n$, right?

Comment: Also notice that the last inequality trivially follows from proving that the pdf of the binomial distribution is convex on the interval $[0,l/2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the inequality holds vacuously if $l$ is not a multiple of four.

Assuming $l=4n$, if we prove that the pdf of $\operatorname{Bin}(\alpha,4n)$ is convex on the interval $[0,2n]$, then the inequality follows from Jensen's inequality. Notice that the inflection points of the pdf of the standard normal distribution occurs in $x=\pm 1$, so it is reasonable to expect that the pdf of $\operatorname{Bin}(\alpha,4n)$ is convex on the set $|x-\mu|\geq\sigma$, or
$$ |x-4n\alpha|\geq\sqrt{4n\alpha(1-\alpha)},$$
so if $\alpha\geq\frac{1}{2}$ we're OK. This is exactly the assumption in the linked paper.